# What is AT&T’s Link Editor Command Language?

Tags: programming, linker, system-v

The man page for `ld` makes reference to `AT&T’s Link Editor Command Language`, however a Google search does not offer a satisfactory explanation as to what `AT&T’s Link Editor Command Language` is or was, other than pointing to said man pages, whereas I expect a Wikipedia page coming up in the first five results.

It seems like there is a vital piece of computing history missing here. Does anyone have some reference or historical documentation on this language? Something we can put in Wikipedia to preserve for posterity?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Link Editor Command Language appears to be described in the *AT&T UNIX™ PC Model 7300 Unix System V Programmers Guide*, chapter 17: The Link Editor.

I found [a copy of the Programmer's Guide (pdf)](http://archive.org/download/ATTUnixPCDocumentation/ATT_UnixPC_Model_7300_Unix_System_V_Programmers_Guide.pdf) at http://www.tenox.net/docs/. The relevant section is on page 524 of the linked `.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I intend to create a Wikipedia entry for this once I have researched it a bit more. (Optional:) Can you help me by defining what the language is (for) / how classified? How would I continue a sentence starting "The AT&T Link Editor Command Language is ...".

Comment: It would be nice to have some background/history as well, e.g. who created it, how it came about etc. How about this for an overview description: "The AT&T Link Editor Command Language is a language used by the Unix ld command for describing how object files and libraries are linked together to produce an executable."